# Grunt requirejs task

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, r.js

I have created requirejs task for concatenating and minifying js files. The files are going to build/js folder. But apart from combined version of js files all other files are also moving to build/js folder. What is the configuration option so that i can avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `removeCombined` option.

From the [example.build.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) file:

> If set to true, any files that were combined into a build bundle will
>   be removed from the output folder.

Comment: Thanks !! that worked. is there any other option so that apart from combined files nothing move to build folder. I have used skipDirOptimize: true to not optimize other files to make build process fast. But still non-optimized files are getting copied to build folder.

Comment: Yes, you can make use of the `fileExclusionRegExp` option for that. You'll need to specify a regular expression that will target files you do not want to be copied to the output folder.